# Sports team model - constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

You are writing a computer program to model sports teams (could be baseball, football, kickball, ultimate, anything!). Your awesome coworker has already written the following classes:

The Team class contains the following methods:

// Constructs a Team object based on the supplied Roster object.
public Team(Roster r)

// Simulates this Team playing a single game, returning a String describing the results of the game.
public String play(Game g)
The Roster class contains the following method (other methods not shown):

// Returns a String containing the names of players on this Roster
public String toString()
The Game class contains methods, but none are shown here.

Design a new class TeamWithStats that inherits from Team, but also keeps track of the team's statistics ("stats"). You should provide the same methods as the superclass, as well as the following new behavior:

// Constructs a TeamWithStats object using information in the Roster object r.
public TeamWithStats(Roster r)

// Returns the information described below
public String getStats();
The getStats method returns a single String containing (in this order): the Roster (in String form, as returned by Roster’s toString method), a "newline" character (\n), the results returned from the first call to play, a "newline" character (\n), the results returned from the second call to play, a "newline" character (\n), the results returned from the third call to play, and so on, through the very last call to play that has been made so far. If play has not yet been called, getStats just returns the Roster (in String form).

Assume all classes other than TeamWithStats were written by your awesome coworker and cannot be changed. In your class, you should include the following:

Any private field(s) you need to add to TeamWithStats
Implementation of the TeamWithStats constructor
Implementation of any methods you need to override.
Implementation of getStats
As always, your methods should call into the superclass as appropriate.

Code:

```
    public class TeamWithStats extends Team
{   
 
    private Roster r;
    
    public TeamWithStats(Roster r) {
        super(r);
        this.r = r;

    }
    public String getStats() {
        return r.toString() + "\n" + super.play(new Game()) + "\n";
    }
}
```

Error message

```
Error on line 12: constructor Game in class Game cannot be applied to given types;
    return r.toString() + "\n" + super.play(new Game()) + "\n";
                                            ^
```

required: java.lang.String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: you'll need to show the Game class.

Comment: read "Game class contains methods, but none are shown here."

Comment: _"constructor Game in class Game cannot be applied to given types;"_ The error is pretty straightforward. You are calling `new Game()` but the constructor requires a `String` from you. So something like `new Game("foo")`. Lookup the class to see what the purpose of the `String` is.

Comment: Don't panic. Read the error message carefully, it contains all the information you need.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. The code works now, but there are other things that arent working, but arent related to this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Your error message is pretty straightforward, carefully read it:

> Error on line 12: constructor Game in class Game cannot be applied to given types;
>
> ```
> return r.toString() + "\n" + super.play(new Game()) + "\n";
>                                         ^
> ```
>
> **required**: `java.lang.String` found: **no arguments**
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

So you are calling `new Game()`, without any arguments. But the constructor in that class requires you to call it with a `String`, like `new Game("foo")`.

If you lookup the code for the class `Game`, you will see something like:

```
public class Game {
    ...

    // Constructor that requires a String as argument
    public Game(String foo) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Check out the class to see what exactly the purpose of that `String` is.

---

### Example

To give you a better feeling for what you did wrong, let me show you another example. Suppose you have a class `Person` and you want that each person has a `String name` and an `int age`. You can achieve this by letting the constructor require both. For example:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getAge() { return age; }
}
```

Now you can create instance of this class by calling the constructor and providing both, a name and an age:

```
Person person = new Person("John", 20);
```

But what you are trying to do is just calling it like `new Person()`, without supplying any name or age, despite the constructor requiring it.

Comment: the class isn't provided in the problem, we just know it exists. After testing the string has no effect on the problem, its just there.

Comment: @attilaaaaaaaaaa I highly doubt. As soon as you call it with a string, this code snippet will compile. Also, you must have access to the class (either the `.java` or `.class` file), otherwise your code would complain that it can not even find the symbol `Game` in the first place.

Comment: Thought I didn't have access to the file, but turns out I do. Here it is class Game
    {
        private String s;
        public Game(String s)
        {
            this.s = s;
        }
        public String getGameInfo()
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

Comment: See, the string is the _game info_. So when you create a Game, you have to provide a _game info_. `new Game("This is a very nice soccer game.")`. And then this snippet will definitely compile.